# Property 'productForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I was trying to make a reactive form but this error "Property 'productForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."
Code for TypeScript file is -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-product',
  templateUrl: './create-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-product.component.css']
})
export class CreateProductComponent implements OnInit {
  productForm:FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.productForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null),
      number: new FormControl(null),
      address: new FormControl(null) 
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.productForm)
  }
}
```

And HTML file for this corresponding file is-

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label  class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label  class="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="number" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label  class="form-label">Address</label>
        <input type="address" class="form-control" formControlName="address" />
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do?

Comment: Move formGroup initialization to constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the rules of your linter confguration except any property to be initialized either when declaring the property or into the constructor.

You can change the rules or move the initialization to the constructor (or the declaration) :

```js
productForm:FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.productForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null),
      number: new FormControl(null),
      address: new FormControl(null) 
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare your variable this way:

```
  productForm!:FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach for this problem:
Go to your angular project "tsconfig.json" file and add `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in the compilerOptions section.

```
` "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
```